# Summary of Data Entered

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have a summary page.

For example, in Page 1 I will ask for customer name, email, orders as shown in the html.

After clicking submit, it will link me to Page 2, where a window will pop up to summarize as follows.

```
Customer name: xxxxxxx
Email: xxxxxxx
No of quantity ordered for item A:xx
No of quantity ordered for item B:xx
No of quantity ordered for item C:xx
Total cost:xx
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head> 
<title> nochange.html </title>
<meta charset = "utf-8" />
  <script type = "text/javascript"  src = "dynValue.js" >
</script>
<style type = "text/css">
  textarea {position: absolute; left: 250px; top: 0px;}
  span {font-style: italic;}
  p {font-weight: bold;}
  td, th, table {border: thin solid black;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
      <form action = "">
  <p>
    <span>
      Customer information 
    </span>
    <br /><br />
    <label>
      Name: 
      <input type = "text"  onmouseover = "messages(0)"
             onmouseout = "messages(4)" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>
      Email: 
      <input type = "text"  onmouseover = "messages(1)"
             onmouseout = "messages(4)" />
    </label>
    <br /> <br /></p>
</form>
<form action = "">
  <h3> Order Form </h3>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th> Product Name </th>
      <th> Price </th>
      <th> Quantity </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th> French Vanilla (1 lb.) </th>
      <td> $3.49 </td>
      <td> <input type = "text"  id = "french"  
                  size ="2" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Hazlenut Cream (1 lb.) </th>
      <td> $3.95 </td>
      <td> <input type = "text"  id = "hazlenut"  
            size = "2" /> </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <th> Columbian (1 lb.) </th>
      <td> $4.59 </td>
      <td> <input type = "text"  id = "columbian"  
            size = "2" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <p>
    <input type = "button"  value = "Total Cost" 
           onclick = "computeCost();" />
    <input type = "text"  size = "5"  id = "cost" 
           onfocus = "this.blur();" />
  </p>


  <p>
    <input type = "submit"  value = "Submit Order" /> 
    <input type = "reset"  value = "Clear Order Form" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
 var helpers = ["Your name must be in the form: \n \
 first name, middle initial., last name",
"Your email address must have the form: \
user@domain",]

function messages(adviceNumber) {
document.getElementById("adviceBox").value = 
                              helpers[adviceNumber];
}
function computeCost() {
var french = document.getElementById("french").value;
var hazlenut = document.getElementById("hazlenut").value;
var columbian = document.getElementById("columbian").value;

document.getElementById("cost").value = 
totalCost = french * 3.49 + hazlenut * 3.95 + 
          columbian * 4.59;
}
```

Comment: It does calculate and show totalCost. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/QSLsF/

Comment: yup..but now how do i capture input from customer and pop up the data input including items + total cost as mentioned in my question?

Comment: Did you notice that the helpers[] array has only 3 elements?

Answer (score 0):

I would think it has something to do with the fact that french, hazlenut and columbian are being treated as strings in your code.  Try using parseInt for each before performing the totalCost calculation.

If you are using html 5 and only newer browsers you may get away with input type=number rather than your input type=text.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to capture and show data entered by user on your main page to second page, you need to submit your form using `<form method="post" action="second.php">` and then in second.php you need to get those values and display as needed.

In order for this to work, you will have to use 'name' attribute on **each** form element. For example:

```
<input type = "text"  size = "5"  id = "cost" name="cost" onfocus = "this.blur();" />
```